# best way to get metadata from pictures in a folder

Tags: excel, image, exiftool

I'm looking for the easiest way to get a maximum of metadata from all pictures of a single folder.

I actually want to make a soft (bash / vba / whatever) where I just have a simple action to do to export all metadata of each pics inside an excel worksheet.

What's about Exiftool ? is that the best technique ?
Is anyone know a soft who do that ?

Thanks for the help, dear community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use exiftool to create a csv file then open that with Excel.

`exiftool -csv *.jpg > data.csv`

Comment: Further reading: [exiftool `-csv` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#csv-CSVFILE), [exiftool FAQ #12, How do I export information from exiftool to a database?](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q12)